# Move arbitrary string to end of command

Tags: bash, scripting

I often find that I've concocted some incantation which I'd like to reuse, but it's far too susceptible to ad-hoc tweaking to store as a function. These commands often have some critical variable component, such as a filename, buried deep within. I'd like to move that component to the end of the command.

For example, my latest witchcraft prints the table definitions of all new `INSERT` statements in a diff file:

```
for T in $(grep -oP "(?<=^\+INSERT INTO \`)[\w-]+(?=\`)" foo.diff | sort -u) ; do docker-compose exec mysql mysqldump --no-data some_database $T | grep -P "^\s*\`|^CREATE|^\) |^\s*CONSTRAINT" | sed "s/ COMMENT .*,$/,/" | sed "s/CONSTRAINT \`\w*\` //" | sed "s/^) ENGINE.*;/);/" ; done
```

Formatted for legibility:

```
for T in $(grep -oP "(?<=^\+INSERT INTO \`)[\w-]+(?=\`)" foo.diff | sort -u)
  do
  docker-compose exec mysql mysqldump --no-data some_database $T
    | grep -P "^\s*\`|^CREATE|^\) |^\s*CONSTRAINT"
    | sed "s/ COMMENT .*,$/,/"
    | sed "s/CONSTRAINT \`\w*\` //"
    | sed "s/^) ENGINE.*;/);/"
done
```

I'm very likely going to want to use this again in the future on a file that is not called `foo.diff`, so I'd like the command to end with the file name. My first inclination would be to just wrap the whole thing in a function, and have the filename be the $1 parameter.

However, it is very likely that I'm going to tweak it further as I run it. Add a bit of sed here, maybe a touch of awk there. So I'd still like the whole command to be on the CLI when I `Ctrl-P` to run it again. Therefore I decided to use a variable:

```
$ FILENAME=diff-03-04.sql
```

That's appropriate for this specific example as I'll be using the same file for each incantation today, but there exist other examples where I'd really like to be able to just tweak the end of the command. So this:

```
$ for Q in $(foo Torvalds bar) ; do baz $Q ; done
```

Would become something akin to (but not necessarily exactly):

```
$ for Q in $(foo SOME_MAGIC_HERE bar) ; do baz $Q ; done < Torvalds
```

Comment: That's why you'd use a script or function to encapsulate the code. Use `type f` for function f to see its definition. Copy and paste to suit

Comment: It's unclear why using a variable would be inappropriate in your last example. Personally, I would put these things into scripts. I would also _strongly_ suggest using `cmd | while read` loops rather than `for in $(cmd)` loops.

Comment: "and have the filename be the `$1` parameter" – `sh -c '…' sh foo.diff`. This however introduces an additional level of quoting.

Comment: @roaima Thank you. The reason that I would prefer to not wrap in a function is because there will be much tweaking from invocation to invocation, especially as I hone in on exactly the code and results I want. I want to run, and have accessible to alter, the entire command each time.

Comment: @Kusalananda If I want to run the code on a dozen different files, then it is much more convenient to Ctrl-P and change the last argument than it is to set the variable anew each time.

Comment: @dotancohen `ls` and `cat` can work on different files. A script that takes one or more arguments or parameters is no different

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I don't understand what you are suggesting, and I'm unsure what to read to learn. Could you expand on that or link to something for me to read? Thank you!

Comment: E.g. `sh -c 'echo "$1"' sh foo.diff` prints `foo.diff`, so this is a way to "have the filename be the `$1` parameter" and "the whole command to be on the CLI". *But* the additional level of quoting can complicate things, especially if you want some shell variable(s) of the *current* shell to be expanded or transferred safely. This "solution" may easily get less convenient than your original problem, therefore it's just a comment.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I see, thank you! That would be great if it didn't require escaping quotes in the actual command. And yes, I'm already using both single and double quotes usually.

Comment: For the record: (re)defining a function and calling it in the same line is possible: `myfunc() { echo "$1"; }; myfunc foo.diff`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Yes, that is what I wound up doing and just typed up an answer explaining it. If you post your comment as an answer then I'll accept it, as it really is the proper solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you have misunderstood the power of a script or function. Personally I prefer scripts because they are self contained and available regardless of the interactive shell I'm using, but a function can do exactly the same thing. For me, systemwide scripts go into `/usr/local/bin` and personal (junk) scripts go into `~/bin`. Both are in my `$PATH`.

Create the directory `~/bin`. Add it to your `$PATH` (`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"`). Now any executable script placed in that directory will be available to you as a new command.

Let's take your example as a case in point. You want the file name to be a use-time selection, so let's make it the first argument of a script.

Create the file `~/bin/tables`:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
for T in $(grep -oP "(?<=^\+INSERT INTO \`)[\w-]+(?=\`)" "$file" | sort -u)
  do
  docker-compose exec mysql mysqldump --no-data some_database "$T"
    | grep -P "^\s*\`|^CREATE|^\) |^\s*CONSTRAINT"
    | sed "s/ COMMENT .*,$/,/"
    | sed "s/CONSTRAINT \`\w*\` //"
    | sed "s/^) ENGINE.*;/);/"
done
```

Make the script executable with `chmod a+x ~/bin/tables` and now you have a new command.

```
tables foo.diff
tables another.diff
```

Comment: I think the whole point of the question is that it's not just the filename that will change, but also some tweaks inside the function itself depending on which filename will be processed, if I understood OP correctly. This is why every invocation will be a little different, potentially, and why OP prefers to get the whole line invoked with readline facilities.

Comment: Thank you roaima. But as ychaouche notes, every invocation will be slightly different, and editing the script file each time is adding friction, not reducing it. Theoretically, I could just keep VIM open and run the file (with `:!./% foo.diff` or `:!% foo.diff` if it's in my PATH) but then doing anything else (e.g. `ls`) becomes a hassle.

Comment: @ychaouche indeed. I thought that that too, but then the OP seemed to suggest in later comments that it was mostly about changing the filename

Comment: @dotancohen sorry, you've lost me: where does `vi`/`vim` fit into the process?

Comment: @roaima Changing the filename, or other arbitrary string, does happen, that is the gist of this question. "How do I take this buried string and make it specifically easier to modify, while I can still modify the whole thing" might be a verbose way of phrasing it.

Comment: With your method of using a script, I would be editing the script in VIM.

Comment: @dotancohen ok. For known changes you can parameterise the value. For unknown changes you would need to create a new script. Or edit an existing command line

Comment: @dotancohen I don't know if that helps but you can actually edit the current command line in your favorite editor by pressing C-x C-e (most terminal I've worked with often have emacs keybindings by default). So you could just revoke the line with readline facilties, then C-x C-e to edit it in your favorite editor (configure $EDITOR global environement variable in your shell's rc file)

Comment: Yes, I do use C-X C-E. But at that point we're editing a command, not a script as this answer suggests to do.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody here has given excellent advice, in the other answer and in the comments. The best method that I've found is to wrap the command in a function and run that function in a single command:

```
$ _() { echo $1; } && _ beer
beer
$
```

Additionally, I've replaced the `for T in $()` syntax with `cmd | while read` as suggested by Kusalananda. Thus the final syntax is as follows:

```
_() { grep -oP "(?<=^\+INSERT INTO \`)[\w-]+(?=\`)" $1 | sort -u | while read -r T ; do docker-compose exec mysql mysqldump --no-data some_database $T | grep -P "^\s*\`|^CREATE|^\) |^\s*CONSTRAINT" | sed "s/ COMMENT .*,$/,/" | sed "s/CONSTRAINT \`\w*\` //" | sed "s/^) ENGINE.*;/);/" ; done } && _ foo.diff
```

Formatted for readability:

```
_() {
  grep -oP "(?<=^\+INSERT INTO \`)[\w-]+(?=\`)" $1
    | sort -u
    | while read -r T ;
      do
      docker-compose exec mysql mysqldump --no-data some_database $T
        | grep -P "^\s*\`|^CREATE|^\) |^\s*CONSTRAINT"
        | sed "s/ COMMENT .*,$/,/"
        | sed "s/CONSTRAINT \`\w*\` //"
        | sed "s/^) ENGINE.*;/);/"
    done
}
&& _ foo.diff
```

This method preserves the ability to tweak anywhere in the command that I need, yet easily change the argument (in this case, the filename), without needing to escape quotes in the commands themselves.

Comment: It's far more robust to write `while IFS= read -t T` and double-quote `"$T"` each time you use it

Comment: The `echo $1` construct can be better replaced with `printf -- "%s\n" "$1"`

Comment: @roaima Thank you! I understand why the `while` construct is better (after googling it) but what is the advantage with `printf` over `echo`? I very much appreciate your ambition to share your knowledge, I am just as ambitions to learn!

Comment: Considering the general case. Some implementations of `echo` action a first argument that begins with a dash. For example `echo -n hello` might suppress the newline after `hello`. Also, with an unquoted `$1` you replace intentional whitepace (such as two or more spaces in a row, or leading/trailing whitespace) with a single space. The `printf` approach guarantees that these unexpected behaviours will not happen.

Comment: @roaima I see, thank you.